# python - how to export data from a csv file in a human-readable form

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with fields that can have variable length.

Is there a way to export it as a text file that can be read easily by a human?
For example, the lines:

```
01,www.example.com,John,smith,34,interior design
1454,www.anothersite.com/portfolio,Alice,Cooper,76,retired
```

should result in something like this:

```
01   : www.example.com               : John  : Smith  : 34 : interior design 
1454 : www.anothersite.com/portfolio : Alice : Cooper : 76 : retired
```

(I've used colons just as an example of separators)

Answer (score 0):

Opening the csv file in something like Excel or LibreOffice Calc would make it readable and create spacing for you.  If however you want to do this in code and specify a length,
something like `field.ljust(width, ' ')` would pad any fields to your desired length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) module along with `csv`.

```
pip install tabulate
```

Here's how:

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate

columns = ["Id", "Website", "Name", "Last Name", "Age", "Occupation"]

with open("data.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
    print(tabulate(rows, tablefmt="pretty", headers=columns))
```

Output:

```
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
|  Id  |            Website            | Name  | Last Name | Age |   Occupation    |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
|  01  |        www.example.com        | John  |   smith   | 34  | interior design |
| 1454 | www.anothersite.com/portfolio | Alice |  Cooper   | 76  |     retired     |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
```